# how can i get data from text type input, radio button,select tag and checkbox for asp.net C#, in aspx.cs page?

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <pre>
           UR NAME <input type="text" id="text1" name="name"/>
           UR AGE <input type="text" id="text2" name="age"/>
           UR Gender <input type="radio" id="Gender" name="Gender" /> Male   
                     <input type="radio" id="Radio1" name="Gender" /> Female
           Select UR club
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckbox1" runat="server" name="ABC" value="ABC" />ABC
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckbox2" runat="server" name="ACC" value="ACC" />ACC
                <input type="checkbox" id="chckbox3" runat="server" name="APAC" value="APAC" />APAC
           <select id="d" name="select_catalog_query1">
                <option>Primary</option>
                <option>Secondary</option>
           </select>
           <input type="submit" id="sub" value="Submit" runat="server" onserverclick="show_Info"/>
        </pre>
        <div><label id="labl1" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I want to show all the info what I get in a label tag id `labl1`. here is my `aspx.cs` page's code.

```
protected void show_Info(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            string txt1 = "us choosen club";
            string txt= "ur name"+" "+"UR age"+" ";
            labl1.InnerText = txt+" "+txt1;
            labl1.Visible = true;
}
```

how can I get all the data of text,select tag, checkbox into show_Info function??

Comment: is there any reason for not using asp.net controls? like asp:TextBox

Comment: noh...i just don't know how to use them.....

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why are you not using the `asp.net` controls instead of using HTML controls with `runat="server"` attribute. You can use `asp.net` controls in such cases they make thing a lot more easier for you.

By the way you can use the `Value` property of html controls.

```
//for input type text
string textValue = text1.Value;

//for checkbox
string checkBoxValue = chckbox1.Value;

// for select-option
string selectedOption = d.Value;
```

Those controls are not accessible on your code behind (.cs page), you need to add `runat="server"` property with them.

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch value from `Request.Form[]` collection

```
var name = Request.Form["name"];
var age= Request.Form["age"];
```